# Respawning in video games

Tags: game

I play a game called GTA. In this game I don't do any Haram stuff, I just roam freely. My question is whenever you die in this game, you respawn in front of a hospitol. Does this come under bringing people back to life? So, if it does, is this shirk?

Comment: Why are you writing the same question when it’s under the same topic?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I already answered (same) your question earlier...

I don’t think it does to be frank.
It’s a video game, it’s programmed by humans. If anyone were to code something, they can simply create it. So for your game, they obviously had coded it so players can respawn. Your game is fictional. It’s not reality.

However, this is completely different from trying to revive someone from the dead in real life. If that were the case, **then it would.**

But since it’s a game, it’s not real but just programmed, **no it wouldn’t**.

What you’re asking is basically something like, “in my game, we can’t pray. Does this fall under the same logic as not praying to Allah?”

And about GTA.
Regardless of what your intentions are, it’s best to stay away from that game because;

1. Filth & haram tailor that game
2. Nudity, explicit women & language surround that game (especially the opening credits to that game)

As a Muslim, please don’t play such a dirty game, regardless of what your intentions are, it’s still haram.